# mysql query with grouping with timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a query which will output data based on last and second last search time. Let me explain the table:

```
id  key         comp    timestamp
1   keyword1    comp1   11-04-2015 23:56
2   keyword2    comp3   12-04-2015 23:56
3   keyword1    comp2   12-04-2015 00:56
4   keyword3    comp4   11-04-2015 23:56
5   keyword3    comp6   11-04-2015 23:56
```

Now the output should be:

```
keyword1    comp1   11-04-2015 23:56    comp2   12-04-2015 00:56
```

Means I need to display the last searched and second last searched comp name of the keyword1...am really helpless on this situation how to proceed....can any one please guide me with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  r1.key
,       r1.comp
,       r1.timestamp
,       r2.key
,       r2.comp
,       r2.timestamp
from    (
        select  *
        from    YourTable
        where   `key` = 'keyword1'
        order by
                timestamp desc
        limit   1 -- First row
        ) r1
left join
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable
        where   `key` = 'keyword1'
        order by
                timestamp desc
        limit   1, 1 -- Skip 1, take 1 --> second row
        ) r2
on      1=1
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/796bc/9/0)